# Table Reference points to the first table not to the right one, why is that happeneing?

Tags: tables, overleaf, appendices

I am using Overleaf as platform to write my paper

My paper has many tables

some of these tables in the middle of the paper and some are in the **Appendix**

The problem is that when i call the Appendix tables by reference, I get the first table in the middle of the page

here is the latex script

if you click on the red part where it is reference to **table_My21**, it will take you to another table in the middle of the paper

how to fix that?

here is the latex script

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{makecell}%


\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom


\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{my paper}


\author*[1]{\fnm{A} \sur{M} \orcid{00}}\email{a}

\author[1]{\fnm{n} \sur{si} \orcid{0000}}\email{dau}
%\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}


\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{cccc}, \orgname{ University}, \orgaddress{\city{Townsville}, \postcode{4811}, \state{Queensland}, \country{Australia}}}


\abstract{bla bla s.}

\keywords{ Coding}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
intro

\section{Background}
\subsection{a}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.




\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Dataset a.}
\label{table_FinalDataset}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}ccccccccccc}
\toprule%
& \multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{Features} & \multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{ICDs} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}\cmidrule{7-11}%
\textbf{\makecell{Report\\ID}} & \textbf{K0004482}  & \textbf{K0224473} & \textbf{G0719349}
& \textbf{U0230431} & \textbf{W0420607} & \textbf{295}
& \textbf{300}  & \textbf{303}  & \textbf{540}
& \textbf{560}\\
\midrule
            1012    &6  &0  &0  &4  &2  &0  &1  &1  &0  &0\\            
            1013    &0  &2  &2  &8  &0  &1  &1  &0  &0  &1  \\          
            1014    &0  &0  &4  &4  &9  &1  &0  &1  &0  &0  \\ 
            \botrule
\end{tabular*}

\vspace{2cm}


\caption{Data b.}
\label{table_BinaryArray}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccccccccc}
\toprule

%\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Report ID}}
%& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Features}}
 \textbf{Diagnosis}
& \textbf{Rep 1}    & \textbf{Rep 2}    & \textbf{Rep 3}
& \textbf{Rep 4}    & \textbf{Rep 5}    & \textbf{Rep 6}
&  \textbf{Rep 7}   & \textbf{Rep 8}
& \textbf{Rep 9}\\

\midrule
            295 &1  &1  &0  &0  &0  &0  &1  &1  &0\\            
            303 &0  &1  &0  &0  &0  &1  &0  &1  &0\\            
            560 &0  &0  &1  &1  &0  &1  &0  &1  &1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}



\section{Something}
\subsection{a}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
{\color{red} The results presented in Tables \ref{table_My21}}




\begin{appendices}
\section{Experiments Results}\label{secA1}


\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{configurations.}
\label{table_My21}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lcccl}
\toprule
\textbf{Dataset Name}
&\textbf{\makecell{(Minutes)}}
&\textbf{A}
&\textbf{V}
&\textbf{H}\\

\midrule
Kitkat (L3-1k) &6.5 &56.52 &54.31 &RF \\
Mars (L3-2k) &6.5 &55.63 &55.05 &PA, Ada \\
\hline
Blue (L3-1k) &32.6 &43.53 &40.53 &GNB, GB \\
Red (L3-2k) &25.2 &43.08 &38.75 &RF, MLP\\
All (L2-8k) &49.8 &56.26 &46.37 &RF, DT \\
All (L2-16k) &52.7 &48.13 &37.82 &BNB, RF \\     
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `sn-jnl` is not a standard class.  If you use `article` instead, do you still have the problem?  Can you delete some of the packages and still have the problem?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I get the first table in the middle of the page". FWIW, after I make your code compilable by adding the dummy instruction `\providecommand\orcid[1]{#1}`, the lone `\ref`-type cross-reference in your example code points to table "A1" -- this is exactly what should be happening.

Comment: @Mico it is still go to Table1 not Table A1. I started fresh project and still does not reference to the right table!!

Comment: Thanks for providing this clarification of what the real issue is, *viz.*, the incorrect hyperlink from the `\ref`-generated cross-reference to its intended target. (It would appear that either the `appendices` package or an untoward interaction between the `appendices` package and the `sn-jnl` document class is causing this issue.) To fix it, please issue the instruction `\renewcommand\theHtable{theHsection.\arabic{table}}` immediately after `\begin{appendices}`. For more information, please see subsection 13.7., "Subordinate counters", on p. 57 of the user guide of the hyperref package.

Comment: @Mico you are genius, it works,
please put it in answer so i can mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turns out not to be with the visual appearance of the cross-references to tables in the appendix, but with the hyperlink embedded in the cross-reference. I didn't perform a deep dive into the *cause* of the issue. It could be caused by either by the `appendices` package itself or by an unfortunate interaction between the `appendices` package and the `sn-jnl` document class.

The `hyperref` package provides a straightforward work-around for cases such as this one: Redefine the properties of a secondary counter, with an "H" prefix, that's associated with the basic `table` counter. Specifically, you should run

```
\renewcommand\theHtable{theHsection.\arabic{table}}
```

You should run this instruction immediately after `\begin{appendices}`.

[image]

[image]

Incidentally, I can't see a valid reason for rendering Table A1 in landscape mode.

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style

\providecommand\orcid[1]{#1} % ??

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{makecell}


\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition} 

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\raggedbottom


\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{my paper}


\author*[1]{\fnm{A} \sur{M} \orcid{00}}\email{a}

\author[1]{\fnm{n} \sur{si} \orcid{0000}}\email{dau}
%\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}


\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{cccc}, \orgname{ University}, \orgaddress{\city{Townsville}, \postcode{4811}, \state{Queensland}, \country{Australia}}}


\abstract{bla bla s.}

\keywords{ Coding}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
intro

\section{Background}
\subsection{a}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.




\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Dataset a.}
\label{table_FinalDataset}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}ccccccccccc}
\toprule%
& \multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{Features} & \multicolumn{5}{@{}c@{}}{ICDs} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}\cmidrule{7-11}%
\textbf{\makecell{Report\\ID}} & \textbf{K0004482}  & \textbf{K0224473} & \textbf{G0719349}
& \textbf{U0230431} & \textbf{W0420607} & \textbf{295}
& \textbf{300}  & \textbf{303}  & \textbf{540}
& \textbf{560}\\
\midrule
            1012    &6  &0  &0  &4  &2  &0  &1  &1  &0  &0\\            
            1013    &0  &2  &2  &8  &0  &1  &1  &0  &0  &1  \\          
            1014    &0  &0  &4  &4  &9  &1  &0  &1  &0  &0  \\ 
            \botrule
\end{tabular*}

\vspace{2cm}


\caption{Data b.}
\label{table_BinaryArray}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccccccccc}
\toprule

%\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Report ID}}
%& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Features}}
 \textbf{Diagnosis}
& \textbf{Rep 1}    & \textbf{Rep 2}    & \textbf{Rep 3}
& \textbf{Rep 4}    & \textbf{Rep 5}    & \textbf{Rep 6}
&  \textbf{Rep 7}   & \textbf{Rep 8}
& \textbf{Rep 9}\\

\midrule
            295 &1  &1  &0  &0  &0  &0  &1  &1  &0\\            
            303 &0  &1  &0  &0  &0  &1  &0  &1  &0\\            
            560 &0  &0  &1  &1  &0  &1  &0  &1  &1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}



\section{Something}
\subsection{a}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\textcolor{red}{The results are presented in \autoref{table_My21}.}


\clearpage

\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand\theHtable{theHsection.\arabic{table}} % <-- new

\section{Experimental results}\label{secA1}

\begin{table}[ht!] % AFAICT, no need for landscape mode
\caption{Configurations.} \label{table_My21}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lcccl@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Dataset Name}
&\textbf{Minutes} & \textbf{A} & \textbf{V} & \textbf{H}\\
\midrule
Kitkat (L3-1k) &6.5 &56.52 &54.31 &RF     \\
Mars (L3-2k) &6.5 &55.63 &55.05 &PA, Ada  \\
\midrule
Blue (L3-1k) &32.6 &43.53 &40.53 &GNB, GB \\
Red (L3-2k) &25.2 &43.08 &38.75 &RF, MLP  \\
All (L2-8k) &49.8 &56.26 &46.37 &RF, DT   \\
All (L2-16k) &52.7 &48.13 &37.82 &BNB, RF \\     
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```